# Ruby Custom Classes, How do you know what to initialize?

Tags: ruby, class

I'm trying to write a small dictionary Ruby app where I can look up existing entries, add and remove entries (ALL ENTRIES ARE PUT INTO A HASH).  So right now I'm creating a Dictionary class and I'm not quite sure what exactly should be 'initialized' method.

I'm still pretty new to Ruby, so if someone could explain what should be initialized at the beginning of a class I'd be extremely grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question. In particular, you should have a specific problem, and it would be great if it is accompanied with a minimal slice of the code you have trouble with. Not knowing how you structured your class (e.g. composition vs. inheritance), we can't even begin to help you. In particular, not doing any initialization is a perfectly okay choice in some cases, as long as the code does what you want.

Comment: @sawa While it's not a great question, your attitude needs adjustment. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/185951 for help with that.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan.  Sorry about posting this here.  I thought I gave just enough information to where I could get some insite, but I'll read the character again in my book to see if I can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you know what to initialize?

Time and experience. In general, #new should:

- Initialize instance variables.
- Configure any object defaults.
- Register itself with observers.
- Housekeeping tasks needed to reach a minimal "ready" state.

Sometimes an object needs to do a lot more work to be "ready" (whatever that means for your class), and #new can just as easily do too little as too much. Finding the right balance *for your application* is what matters, so feel free to open **new questions** here or on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) with more concrete questions and some actual code.